# Import specific number of rows from CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code for Google Macros that allows me to import all the rows in a particular CSV into Google Sheets. However, I'm having some issues synchronizing my uploads with other calculations I have taking place which leads to time out issues.

I think the easiest way to fix this will be to just import a specific range of cells and do that a couple of times.

Please suggest how I can modify the code below (which works) to import say Rows 1 to 2000.

```
 function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("DualCreditExport.csv").next(); 

var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('CURRENT');
 sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
var start = 0; var numRows =2000;
 sheet.getRange(start+1, 1, numRows, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData.slice(start, start+numRows));
```

Note that the [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) function is defined as follows:

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
```

and that the row and column starts from 1 here and in an array it starts from 0.